# USB on ATmega32U4 powered at 3.3V

Tags: arduino, usb-device, atmega32u4

I have an already-designed board that uses an ATmega32U4 (a board of our own design).  It is USB-powered at 5V and it has an external 16MHz crystal.

Below is a screencapture of the relevant portion of the schematic:

[image]

The firmware is built as an Arduino project (a single `.ino` file), based on the Pro Micro.

I have several reasons to move the design to 3.3V (still USB-powered, so I can simply add an LDO to generate the 3.3V);  thus, the external crystal will have to be 8MHz.  However, my doubt/question is about the 48MHz internally-generated USB clock signal:  I don't see anywhere in the `.ino` file anything related to setting up the MCU's PLL; would that be part of the bootloader? Would I need to adjust the bootloader? Obtain and flash a bootloader image specifically for 8MHz clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bootloader uses this module to initialize the USB hardware:
[USBCore.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp)

This is the relevant code fragment:

```
// ATmega32U4
#if defined(PINDIV)
#if F_CPU == 16000000UL
    PLLCSR |= (1<<PINDIV);                   // Need 16 MHz xtal
#elif F_CPU == 8000000UL
    PLLCSR &= ~(1<<PINDIV);                  // Need  8 MHz xtal
#else
#error "Clock rate of F_CPU not supported"
#endif
```

I think you must recompile the bootloader with the option

F_CPU = 8000000

in the caterina Makefile or try to use the caterina-LilyPadUSB bootloader. That seems to be compatible to your design and expects an 8 MHz crystal.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to mark it as answered;  I was tempted to do so as soon as I was convinced that this was the correct answer, but then I figured I'd wait to receive and try the boards — that took longer than anticipated, but finally yesterday we received them, and indeed things worked following your suggestion!

Comment: BTW, we just downloaded the binary (caterina-LilyPadUSB.hex) and flashed it, and then we could flash the Arduino code via the USB.